# DotNetNuke, Intermodule communication and UpdatePanels

Tags: module, updatepanel, dotnetnuke, ascx

I have a 3rd-party DotNetNuke module which allows Intermodule Communications. I wrote a module that interacts with this 3rd-party module. However, the 3rd-party module relies on a complete postback or a complete redirect in the form of Page.Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(TabId), true) from my module to refresh the content in the 3rd-party module, which refreshes the entire page, of course.

On a whim, I modified the 3rd-party .ascx, surrounding the entire existing .ascx code with an update panel. It worked. I can skip the redirect statement and simply push the IMC data to the other module. The module refreshes without refreshing the entire page. Note, I don't have access to the codebehind for the 3rd-party module, just the view.ascx.

This does not seem like a great solution for anyone except me and servers under my control because I can modify the 3rd-party view.ascx.

When I look at the rendered code in Chrome, I see my update panel as a simple div --  -- and the rest of the module as it should be within that div. How does IIS/ASP know that div is an update panel? Is there anyway to programmatically do what I did manually in adding the update panel?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot wrap an existing aspx Control with another Control programatically. You can only do that if all the Controls are generated with code.